# Query Filter: IIf with return >= case

Tags: sql, ms-access

CIAO!

I need to create a Query filtered in this way:

```
IIf([Forms]![Discipline_Bah]![F]=">=1",>=1, like [Forms]![Discipline_Bah]![F] )
```

But the >=1 return always 0.

How can I solve this?
thanks for all the answers!

Edit: added more details:
I've a form with a ComboBox with the parameters 0; >=1;
I wish to filter the data in a query, according to value present in the ComboBox.
(the combobox is a string)

```
iif([combobox]=">=1", then filter >=0; else filter =[combobox])
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.  The question is not clear.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: Combobox has only 0 and ">=1" listed?

Answer (score 0):

Operators (>=, =, etc) cannot be dynamic in query object. Have to use a static operator and then IIf() determines what parameter to return.

Consider:

`WHERE fieldname LIKE IIf(combobox = "All", "*", combobox)`

If your requirements are really more complicated than indicated, advise not to use dynamic query object. Use VBA to conditionally build filter criteria and apply to form or report. Or use VBA to manipulate QueryDefs to modify query object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use the generic "*", 'cause the values are more, "from -100, to +100) and I wish to sort more better, for example exclude ONLY the 0, or only the negative, or just a single number: example only "2"

Comment: Details like that should be within your question. My answer is based on info provided in question. Caveat still applies - operators cannot be dynamic in query object. Can only advise not to use dynamic query. Use VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report.